# htaccess rewrite rule targeting third variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite an URL in order to drive the server to open the new URL when the old is typed.

I have 3 get vars in the old urls and I would like to target some of them in the reqrite process.

What I do is:

```
RewriteRule ^oldforum/topic/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/page/[0-9]+$ http://newforum.website.com/Topic-$1?page=$3 [L,R=301]
```

I do not need the second variable, only first and third.

So, typing the old URL:

http://website.com/oldforum/topic/some-title-here-4526/page/3

I get:

http://newforum.website.com/Topic-some-title-here?page=

so no third var is shown.

Am I missing anything? Clues?

Thank you ver much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put brackets around

```
[0-9]+$
```

to capture it.

```
RewriteRule ^oldforum/topic/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)$ http://newforum.website.com/Topic-$1?page=$3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: what a fool I am! Thank you. I just didn't notice I forgot them.

Comment: Don't be hard on yourself @Aptivus - I can't count the number of times when I've been staring directly at something and just couldn't see it. Sometimes a fresh pair of eyes is just what you need!